# Symfony 1.4 re-creating sessions/sessionid when changing authentication

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm using symfony 1.4 and it appears that every time a user is authenticated symfony recreates a session for the user. For example, if I visit a site and am not logged in I have a different session id then if I log in I have a new one, then when I log out I have yet another new one. This wasn't so in symfony 1.0 and I am wondering if this is how it's supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked 1.0's source code, it did not exist there.
Versions 1.1 and above regenerate the session ID every time the authentication is changed, or a credential is added/removed.
This is a very good security measure, prevents session fixation attacks.

[Here's a link](http://trac.symfony-project.org/changeset/9942) to the relevant changeset in trac.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. I'm trying to implement "who's online" feature on site using database sessions, and not sure how to accomplish this now that there are so many expired sessions

Comment: You may try subclassing sfSessionStorage to somehow flag the current session in the regenerate() function, then tell symfony in the factories.yml to use your class.

Comment: I just decided to set user id in session db manually during login and unsetting it during logout

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct behavior. It's rather related to PHP sessions than how symfony handles them. I don't think it used to be different in symfony 1.0.

Session id should be unique and hard to guess. If you would always get the same session id than someone who once sniffed it could use it every time he wants  (store it in a cookie and use website with your credentials).

Comment: I mean it changes it every time authentication happens, so if you visit site, log in and log out right away, you've already had 3 different session ids. First is created when you first visit site, and remains the same until you log in. When you log in a new session id is created and as long as you remain logged in it remains same. hen when you log out it assigns yet another one. In Symfony 1.0 this was not so.

Comment: In that case you might be right about symfony 1.0. Anyway it's there in 1.4 for security reasons. Nice read about session fixation (and session security in general): http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html